# How do I browse a sandboxed flatpak application's settings with dconf-editor?

Tags: dconf, flatpak

Flatpak applications do not write in system's `dconf`, but they do in the one inside the sandbox. How do I browse (like with `dconf-editor`) sandboxed applications' configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsettings` from within the sandboxed app. For example, I use Evolution via Flatpak. To enter the sandbox, run this from the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.evolution.mail
```

From there, you can use `gsettings` as normal.

Comment: You mean using `gsettings` from the command line of the package's sandboxed shell? So, no dconf-editor for flatpaks?

Comment: No. Even within LibreOffice, which has access to the whole system, `dconf-editor` doesn't exist.